# How to manage IntelliJ IDEA contexts

Tags: intellij-idea

Using **IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2.4**, I can save, load, and clear contexts from the Tools menu:

`Tools > Tasks & Contexts > Save Context`

`Tools > Tasks & Contexts > Load Context`

`Tools > Tasks & Contexts > Clear Context`

When the list of contexts come up, I don't have any control on how to delete the context from the list. The `Clear Context` option, only removes all the files loaded from that context from the view in the IDE. It doesn't remove that context from the list of contexts.

How do I remove contexts from the list of contexts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was tested on:

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2.4
Build #IU-162.2032.8, built on September 9, 2016
JRE: 1.8.0_112-release-b343 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
```

When you do `Tools > Tasks & Contexts > Load Context`, then for each context you can press the <kbd>Right Arrow</kbd> key to get the `Load` or `Remove` options. Choosing the latter removes the Context :

[image]

Comment: I totally didn't see the triangle there... **Thank You!!** I appreciate you pointing this out! I've confirmed it works for me!

Comment: Its something that they could do better in the app. Once you discover the menu, you still have to delete them one by one ;)

Comment: @Ashutosh Jindal: Is it possible to update/modify the context?

Answer (score 0):

**For bulk deletion of Intellij contexts**

I have intellij installed as a snap in linux.
Contexts are stored in a zip file.
The location is for example

```
/home/tim/.config/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.3/tasks/
```

the relevant zip is named like so

```
myproject.contexts.zip
```

Exit intellij.

In the archive, delete unwanted contexts, each of which is a file in the archive. For example, you may expand the archive, delete the contexts you don't want and re-zip it. Or perhaps you can edit them in-place.

Restart intellij. They are gone.